# Angular lazy loading router configuration

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, angular-router, angular-module

I want to lazy load a module in the angular 2+ application.For that  in '**app-routing.module**' file I have following code.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AbcdComponent } from './abcd/abcd.component';


const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'portfolio', loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule'},
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule'},
    { path: 'abcd', component:AbcdComponent}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [
   AbcdComponent

  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now, in Lazy Module I have the following code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LazyParentComponent } from './lazy-parent/lazy-parent.component';
import { LazyChildComponent } from './lazy-child/lazy-child.component';

import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'load-me', component: DashBoardComponent },
    { path: 'load-you', component: PortfolioComponent }

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    LazyParentComponent,
    LazyChildComponent,

  ]
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

This is good enough to route https://example.com/portfolio/load-me to  DashBoardComponent and https://example.com/portfolio/load-you to PortfolioComponent.

But the issue is I want to have a lazy module and for route like this https://example.com/portfolio I want to point to PortfolioComponent and https://example.com/dashboard to DashBoardComponent. Both components should be lazily loaded .Also, both components are in same module.I searched through internet but could not get any solution.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. For each route inside of the AppRoutingModule, there needs to be its own module & and routing. So for example:

Dashboard Routes:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from 'some path';

export const DashboardRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(DashboardRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Dashboard Module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [DashboardRoutingModule]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

App Routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'portfolio', loadChildren: './PathTooPortfolio#PortfolioModule'},
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './PathToDashboard#DashboardModule'},
    { path: 'abcd', component:AbcdComponent}
];
```

Just setup Portfolio the same way as I have Dashboard.